# How to Enable "Application: Specify the maximum log file size (KB)" through registry key

Tags: registry, regedit

There is an option in gpedit.msc to enable "Application: Specify the maximum log file size "

Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Event Log Service\Application\Specify the maximum log file size (KB)

But I wan t to enable from registry key. How can I enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `REG_DWORD` type key with name `MaxSize` having log size (KB) as the value in following path.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\Application
```

**OR**

Save text file containing following and save as `any_name.reg`. Double click to apply. Here `00000400` is the log file size in hexadecimal. (This is a windows 8 registry file)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\Application]
"MaxSize"=dword:00000400
```

Delete above register key to disable.

[group policy edit - registry mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms815238.aspx)

Comment: So, You are saying If I will create the above registry key then by default "Application: Specify the maximum log file size" will get enabled. We dont need to update or create any registry key explictly. right?

Comment: Thank You @TRiNE. I have tested the above scenario and is working as expected.